# Data model question: how to qualify 3rd objects

Tags: mysql, sql, model

I'm dealing with slightly different types hence for clarity of what I'm trying to achieve I have decided to use metaphor.

Let's say you need to create tables that describe projects by two architectural bureaus:

1st only deals with 3D plans
2nd only deals with 2D sketches

I have the following table

```
mysql> describe sketch;
+------------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+
| Field            | Type                          | Null | Key | Default           |
+------------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+
| project_id       | binary(16)                    | NO   | PRI | NULL              |
| company_id       | binary(16)                    | NO   | PRI | NULL              |
| type             | enum('2D','3D','N/A')         | YES  |     |'N/A'              |
+------------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+
```

As you can see project_id & company_id form the PRIMARY KEY

The issue arises when in some exceptional circumstances the same company takes on 2D and 3D task under the same project ID.

Or the same company starts working on two or more sub-projects of the same type (e.g. both are 2D sketches) but within the realm of let's call it parent project with exactly the same ID.

One quick and dirty fix would be simply to add unique ID to the above table but it wouldn't work for me, because there are various reports and and other functions which basically do this: `SELECT blah FROM sketch WHERE project_id=XXX AND company_id`

I could add code to filter the results from the above SQL but I can't really change the structure or the table.

Any ideas of what options do I have?

Appreciate any ideas!

And thank you very much beforehand!

Comment: It seems to me, that the sketch's dimensionality is independent of the both the company and project to which it belongs.

Answer (score 2):

As you describe the problem, company/project is *not* a primary key.  You describe circumstances where uniqueness is violated.

Then company/project/type does seem to be a unique key and a *candidate* primary key.  I would say that you should have a numeric primary key and declare the tripartite key as unique.